# Hide content ajax success if

Tags: html, ajax

I'm trying to hide content of this td, according to ajax success status, is customer status equal to authorized content should be hide, how to do this?

```
'<td class="actions">\n' +
'    <a ' + (customer.status == 'Authorized' ? 'disabled' : '') + ' class="btn-sm btn-default editBtn"\n' +
'       data-target="#exampleModal"\n' +
'       data-toggle="modal"\n' +
'       data-cif=' + customer.cif + '' +
'       data-status=' + customer.status + '>' +
'        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt">\n' +
'        </i>Edit</a>\n' +
'</td>' +
```

Comment: Are you storing html into variable and then push to DOM? Can you share more details how you manipulate this HTML before actually rendering on webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of appending a disabled attribute you could append a class name when it's authorized, like this:

```
'<td class="actions">\n' +
'    <a class="btn-sm btn-default editBtn '+ (customer.status == 'Authorized' ? 'hide' : '') +'"\n' +
'       data-target="#exampleModal"\n' +
'       data-toggle="modal"\n' +
'       data-cif=' + customer.cif + '' +
'       data-status=' + customer.status + '>' +
'        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt">\n' +
'        </i>Edit</a>\n' +
'</td>' +
```

And then on your CSS side you can have this:

```css
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```